# tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: name must be a byte string

Tags: python, linux, twitter, upload, photo

I have an error to upload photo to twitter from python
I'm having trouble with the following code:
(I work with Linux)

```
auth = OAuthHandler (consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token (access_token, access_token_secret)
api = API (auth)
img = "camera.jpeg"
api.update_with_media (img, status = "Test")
```

I returned the following error and I have no idea how to fix it:

> tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: name must be a byte
>   string

I hope you can help me
Thank you

Comment: If you are using Python 3.x, then the problem is most likely that your img variable is UTF-8 instead of ANSI / ASCII, since UTF-8 is the default in 3.x.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.9